# Conditionally add debug flags when building a Go program

Tags: bash, makefile, variable-expansion

I'm writing a Makefile for a Go application, and would like to be able to pass in an environment variable to specify debug flags for the go build command.

The script for building the service without debug flags looks like this:

`cd ./authentication-service && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ${AUTH_BINARY} ./cmd/api`

I'd like to be able to inject these flags after the `go build` part of the command, like so:

`cd ./authentication-service && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -gcflags=all="-N -l" ${AUTH_BINARY} ./cmd/api`

I've read that you can use the `echo` command to send arguments like this, but when I try the following, I get an error

```
cd ./authentication-service && env GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build `if [ "${DEBUG}" = 'auth' ]; then echo '-gcflags=all="-N -l"'; fi` -o authApp ./cmd/api
invalid value "all=\"-N" for flag -gcflags: unterminated " string
usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
make: *** [build_broker] Error 2
```

How can I conditionally supply `-gcflags=all="-N -l"` to this build command when a certain environment variable check returns true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Comment: Even though you're not exactly using a variable, the basic problem is the same - syntax parsing happens before expansions are processed in your command line, so the quotes embedded in whatever you echo are only treated as literal characters and have no syntactic value. This means word splitting will split `-gcflags=all="-N -1"` into `-gcflags=all="-N` and `-1"` which causes the unterminated error.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: The usual solution is to change the `Makefile` so that you can override options at `make` time. But you want that for portability, not flexibility. The debug target should be separate so that you can't mistake the debug binary for a production binary.

Comment: Ended up using a normal bash if/else directly in the makefile rather than trying to inline this because the target binary was also different in production and debugging.Thanks all.